# Upgrading to Web API 2 breaks application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, umbraco7

I have an Umbraco 7 application which uses V4.0 assemblies for things like System.Web.WebHost, System.Web.Http and related assemblies.  I'm trying to get a Web API2 dll working with the Umbraco application, and am having a tough time.

If I use assembly redirection to default to V5.0 assemblies, the app breaks when Umbraco loads and attempts to use a controller.  The problem here is that in V5.0 of System.Web.Http, ApiController now has a check when setting Request.  This check always fails and throws InvalidOperationException:

```
set
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw Error.PropertyNull();
    }
    HttpRequestContext requestContext = value.GetRequestContext();
    HttpRequestContext httpRequestContext = this.RequestContext;
    if (requestContext != null && requestContext != httpRequestContext)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SRResources.RequestContextConflict);
    }
    this.ControllerContext.Request = value;
    value.SetRequestContext(httpRequestContext);
    RequestBackedHttpRequestContext requestBackedHttpRequestContext = httpRequestContext as RequestBackedHttpRequestContext;
    if (requestBackedHttpRequestContext != null)
    {
        requestBackedHttpRequestContext.Request = value;
    }
}
```

The other thing I'm trying is to have both DLLs loaded and used appropriately.  In this case I'm running into an error, but don't know if I'm doing it correctly.  All I've done is added folders to keep separate versions of the same dlls, and wire them up in the web.config using something like this:

```
<probing privatePath="webapi2_dlls;" />
```

error:
    CS1705: Assembly 'WebApi, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Is there hope?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Umbraco was built with older version(4.0) of Web API. You can try again after adding the following binding redirect into the config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: When I use V5.0, Umbraco at one point builds a controller on the fly, and sets the Request member on it.  In V5.0, there are check does that will throw an exception if not met.  See my question

Comment: I think i missed that part...also are you using `5.1` or `5.0` of Web API?

Comment: I'm actually using 5.1, but it looks like the problems I'm having were introduced in 5.0